# How do I "switch" with Mercurial

Tags: svn, version-control, mercurial, dvcs

How do I do what `svn switch` does, in Mercurial?

That is change my working directory to switch to another branch in the repository?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

```
hg update -r<REV>
```

The [update](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/update) command will switch to a specified revision.

Comment: Just a note: if you use named (internal) branches, you can switch to the branch name with -r also: 'hg update -r <branch>'

Comment: I think this needs to be hg update -C <branch>, not -r. As @Danmar says in his answer, the hg branches and hg branch commands are also useful.

Comment: Beginner mistake, be sure you've done hg pull first (so that you have the branch locally to switch to)

Answer (score 33):

The switch command does two things in Subversion:

> 1. Update the working copy to mirror a new URL within the repository.
>      This behaviour is similar to '`svn update`', and is the way to
>      move a working copy to a branch or tag within the same repository.
> 2. Rewrite working copy URL metadata to reflect a syntactic change only.
>      This is used when repository's root URL changes (such as a scheme
>      or hostname change) but your working copy still reflects the same
>      directory within the same repository.

The `hg update foo` command matches the former most closely if you switch from, say, `/trunk` to `/branches/foo` in Subversion.

If you want to do the latter, then simply edit `.hg/hgrc`. You'll find a `[paths]` section that looks like this:

```
[paths]
default = http://example.net/something
```

and you can change this default push/pull URL to something else as you see fit. You can also add other entries to this section if you often need to push/pull from other locations. If you want to pull from one location, but push to another, then add a `default-push` entry.

Answer (score 24):

I you want to switch branches, do the following:

First check what branches are available, type `hg branches`. This will list all the available branches.

Next determine which branch you are currently working on, type `hg branch`. This will tell you what is your current branch.

Finally to switch a branch (**and wipe all local changes**), type `hg update -C name-of-branch`. This will switch you to the branch name you specified.

Verify by typing `hg branch` again.

Comment: Note even if you exclude the -C clean option any local uncommitted changes will be removed when doing this.  If you want to keep uncommitted changes shelve them first :o)

Answer (score 1):

To switch to a remote branch 'tip':

```
hg pull -u <remote_branch>
```

For local branch (already up-to-date) just:

```
hg update -r <local_branch>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate answer, in case by "branch" you mean "another clone of the repo that lives in some arbitrary location on the net": you can't.

In other words, given a repo at hg.a.com, and a clone of that repo hg.b.com, there is no command like

```
hg switch hg.b.com .
```

(using svn parlance there, assuming your current directory is the root of a clone of hg.a.com).

However, you can clone hg.a.com, locally clone that clone (which should be relatively inexpensive), and then pull from hg.b.com to pick up any additional changes that might live there.

Comment: I find it easier to add another path to the `[paths]` section in the `.hg/hgrc` file, or simply change the default path listed there. See `hg help paths` for more info.